# Mocking a Service that returns Cats EitherT with Guice and MockitoSugar

Tags: scala, playframework, mockito, scala-cats, mockito-scala

I am trying to write some functional tests, and I want to mock a service that consumes an external provider. But I can not set up the mock for the functions that return `EitherT`

This is the Trait whose implementation call the external service

```
@ImplementedBy(classOf[ExternalServiceImpl])
trait ExternalService {
  def index: EitherT[Future, String, JsValue]
}
```

In the CustomAppPerSuite trait I set up

```
val mockExternalService = mock[ExternalService]

 implicit override lazy val app = new GuiceApplicationBuilder()
.in(Mode.Test)
.overrides(bind[ExternalService].toInstance(mockExternalService))
.build()

val externalService = app.injector.instanceOf[ExternalService]
```

Then When I try to mock the succesful response

```
  "ExternalController#index" should {

    "return index data" in {
      doReturn(EitherT.rightT(Json.parse("""{"key": "value"}""")).when(externalService).index
      val fakeRequest = FakeRequest(GET, "/api/external")
      val result = externalController.index().apply(fakeRequest)
      status(result) mustBe OK
    }
```

But I get this error

```
[error]  found   : cats.data.EitherT[cats.package.Id,Nothing,JsValue]
[error]  required: cats.data.EitherT[scala.concurrent.Future,String,JsValue]
[error]   def index = EitherT.rightT(
```

I only want to mock the successful response, because it is what I am testing. Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try helping the compiler out by providing some type parameters to `rightT` like so

```
EitherT.rightT[Future, String](Json.parse("""{"key": "value"}"""))
```

instead of

```
EitherT.rightT(Json.parse("""{"key": "value"}"""))
```

Comment: Thank you @Mario_Galic it worked, I did that and `import cats.implicits._`

Comment: @Mario_galic check mockito-scala-cats, it gives a simpler syntax for that scenario

Answer (score 3):

With mockito-scala-cats you could write that in a much more succint way

```
Json.parse("""{"key": "value"}""") willBe returnedF by externalService.index
//or
externalService.index shouldReturnF Json.parse("""{"key": "value"}""")
```

The library will look at the return type of `externalService.index` and get the appropiate `cats.Applicative`(s) to make this work smoothly.

Another advantage if you're running on Scalatest is that you can mix-in `ResetMocksAfterEachTest` and get all the mocks you wired into the play fake app to be automatically reset before each test.

Check [here](https://github.com/mockito/mockito-scala) for more details

Comment: thank you for your answer, does mockito-scala-cats support spy?

Comment: yes it does, it's just syntax sugar for the stubbing api